# Gaining internet access during installation over XP

Tags: drivers, wireless, system-installation

I am trying to install over XP.
When booted in XP connect wirelessly and it is working.
When I enter Ubuntu set up there is no connection showing.
I've tried to edit the connection but it is not detecting my wireless.

I suspect this may be because the wireless driver (for Ubuntu?) is not installed or booted.
(I'm not an expert).

How would you advise I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, if possible, to gain internet access with a wired ethernet connection, if possible. If this is not possible, you will have the best luck installing with working wireless if you install the latest Ubuntu version 13.10. There are drivers included in the October 2013 version that were not yet available in Ubuntu 12.04. The exception is that Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS includes the same kernel and therefor the same drivers as 13.10.

If you still find no wireless driver and therefor connectivity, I'd go ahead and install without internet and research and install a driver after installation. Search your pci.id from the terminal command:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Here is an example from my machine:

```
Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:4239]
```

If you can't find a method to install your wireless drivers after a search, post a new question here.